# LARGE_INTEGER value gets changed while marshalling : from LARGE_INTEGER to UINT64 (C) to C#'s uint64

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, endianness, deviceiocontrol

I try to marshal `NdisGetCurrentSystemTime` result to a C# program via ioctl.

```
LARGE_INTEGER data;
NdisGetCurrentSystemTime (&data );
marshal_data->time = (UINT64)(data.QuadPart / 10^6);
    DBGPRINT(("Time: %64u", marshal_data->time));
```

At C# receiver side, the time field is defined as uint64; there's also a couple of other uint64 fields in the marshalled structure. However, when doing

```
    String.Format(("Time was {0}", recv_data->time))
```

I get unexpectedly large number that differs from the one in DBGPRINT.

C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    ...
    public UInt64 time
```

C:

```
    struct _marshalme {
    ... 
    UINT64 time
    ...
    }
```

Is there anything going weird with a byte order?

Comment: Your DBGPRINT does not print the time, it misses a parameter: `DBGPRINT(("Time: %64u"));`

Comment: 10^6 doesn't make sense either.  The simple explanation is that the C# structure declaration is just wrong so that the field gets misaligned.  You avoided a good answer by not posting the complete declarations.

Comment: @Wimmel, in actual version, there is a parameter. I've been trying to avoid posting lots of code to get a minimal example though. fixing.

Comment: It's very difficult to help when we have to guess at what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`LARGE_INTEGER` represents a [64-bit **signed** integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383713%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I expect your problems come from using `UInt64` instead of `Int64`.

Comment: but the only difference between signed and unsigned is the most significant bit. That should be unset, which means the value should be the same whether taken as a signed or unsigned value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was mainly in improper struct alignment thus different size; but for some reason, it seems to keep damaging data at transfer (e.g. last DBGPRINT prints saved value correctly) for int32, int64 cases even when size is same; I've been forced to use

```
  long startTime;
  long padding;
```

to receive proper value as C#'s long, other ways of marshalling that value failed. Will post more completed sample later, unless that - the question is closed.

Comment: The fact that the issue was struct alignment shows how lacking in detail the question was. You really didn't give us anywhere near enough information to tackle the problem.